# Powershell array of objects add together objects with same value

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to add together counts with equal names.
The array looks something like this:

```
Name  Count
----  -----
6027     12
4999      6
3018      5
1008      3
1006     19
6027     12
4065     10
3018      9
4999      7
489       4
1008      3
5016     19
```

I would like to add up all counts with equal names.
Wanted result would look like this:

```
Name  Count
----  -----
6027     24
4999      6
3018     14
1008      6
1006     19
4065     10
4999      7
489       4
5016     19
```

My best take is to Group the Object by name thus far, which does not produce the wanted output. (Numbers are a bit different than in the above example)

```
$list | Group-Object name | sort count -Descending
$list
```

Output:

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                             
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                             
    8 3018                      {@{Name=3018; Count=5}, @{Name=3018; Count=9}, @{Name=3018; Count=9}, @{Name=3018; Count=9}...}                                                                   
    7 6027                      {@{Name=6027; Count=12}, @{Name=6027; Count=12}, @{Name=6027; Count=12}, @{Name=6027; Count=12}...}                                                               
    7 4999                      {@{Name=4999; Count=6}, @{Name=4999; Count=7}, @{Name=4999; Count=16}, @{Name=4999; Count=12}...}                                                                 
    7 1008                      {@{Name=1008; Count=3}, @{Name=1008; Count=3}, @{Name=1008; Count=3}, @{Name=1008; Count=3}...}                                                                   
    4 1006                      {@{Name=1006; Count=19}, @{Name=1006; Count=12}, @{Name=1006; Count=6}, @{Name=1006; Count=30}}                                                                   
    3 4065                      {@{Name=4065; Count=10}, @{Name=4065; Count=35}, @{Name=4065; Count=30}}                                                                                          
    3 5016                      {@{Name=5016; Count=19}, @{Name=5016; Count=18}, @{Name=5016; Count=20}}
```

Thanks four your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code and what does not work with it.

Comment: As i am slowly learning Powershell and working with hashtables the first time, i have nothing to really share sadly. I tried different foreach itterations, which i could not get to work, aswell as ```Group-Object name | sort count -Descending```, which does not provide the wanted output.

Comment: I have added the output of ```Group-Object name | sort count -Descending``` above.

Comment: How do you actually populate such a hashtable? Duplicate keys are not allowed in hash tables.

Comment: The above hashtable is the result of deleting unnecessary information out of a different hashtable with: 

```$list.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name   = $_.Name
        Count = $_.Count
    }
}```

Comment: So, it's not a Hashtable, but an array of **objects**. Quite a difference..

Comment: You know my next question, don't you?  ;-) :-D

Comment: You’re half-way there, but the ```Count``` column in the output from ```Group-Object``` is not related to the ```Count``` property in your input - it’s the *number* of items in your input that contain the key value. For example, there are 8 items with the name ```3018``` - you can see these items in the ```Group``` column. You need to add up all the items in each row to get the total of your original ```Count``` property for each ```Name``` value.

Comment: It is probably a lot faster to actually use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable) which is based on a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm): `$List |ForEach-Object -Begin { $HashTable = @{} } -Process { $HashTable[$_.Name] += $_.Count } -End { $HashTable }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iRon's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009228/powershell-array-of-objects-add-together-objects-with-same-value#comment127244757_72009228) proposes a nice and efficient solution to the problem using a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) where the **Keys** are the unique values of the `Name` property and the **Values** are the sum of the `Count` property. We can use the generated hash table to update the object you already have.

Below example assumes `$obj` has the array of objects you have displayed in your question.

```
$map = @{}
foreach($i in $obj) {
    $map[$i.Name] += [int] $i.Count
}

foreach($i in $obj) {
    $i.Count = $map[$i.Name]
}

$obj # => Should be now updated
```